# HSQLDB - Oracle to_char(integer) throws " Unexpected Token : )"

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hsqldb

I'm doing integration testing in a Hsqldb. My production database is an Oracle Database.

---

### Versions

- Hibernate : 4.1.3.final.
- Hsqldb : 2.3.3. ( I can't use the 2.3.4 because it can't run all my junit tests in one click.)

---

### My problem

To create my test database, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.inspire-software.com/en/index/view/articles-design-and-impl-dbunit-hibernate-integration-testing.html) with minor modifications. Everything works fine except for the methods that use the TO_CHAR(integer) function from Oracle. For those methods, I got an `unexpected token: )`

**This is the code that causes the exception**

```
select ="select p.name, to_char(p.id) "
        + " from t_player p " +
        "inner join t_job job on j.id=p.id_job ";
```

**This is a part of my unit test**

```
public void testFindPlayer() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:DB", "sa", "");
    String syntax_ora = "SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE";
    PreparedStatement ps_ora = connection.prepareStatement(syntax_ora);
    ps_ora.execute();
    ps_ora.close();
    connection.close();

    List<String[]> actual_player = Player.findPlayer("Name");
    List<String[]> expected_player =  new ArrayList<String[]>(); 
    //etc..
```

**This is the exception**

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: )
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readSQLFunction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readColumnOrFunctionExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesFactor(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesCommonValueExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadValueExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSelect(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
```

---

### How I tried to fix it

1) I try another function from Oracle that is `to_char(number,'format')`. 
Basically, I change the select part with the following:

```
select ="select p.name, to_char(p.id,'999999') "
    + " from t_player p " +
    "inner join t_job job on j.id=p.id_job ";
```

But then, I got this exception : `incompatible data type in operation`

2) I put the `SET DATABASE SQL OSYNTAX` part into comments

The same exceptions are raised.

Do you have an idea on how to fix this issue please?

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HSQLDB's built-in TO_CHAR function supports only date and timestamp arguments.

You can create a user-defined TO_CHAR function for numeric values. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TO_CHAR(param DECIMAL) RETURNS VARCHAR(20) 
    RETURN CAST(param AS VARCHAR(20))

CREATE FUNCTION TO_CHAR(param DECIMAL, format VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS VARCHAR(20) 
    RETURN CAST(param AS VARCHAR(20))
```

Now TO_CHAR(p.id) will return the id as a string and the two-arge version also returns the same.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! (Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error using the `CAST` function, like this:

```
cast(id as VARCHAR)
```

But the correct is:

```
cast(id as VARCHAR(20))
```